# trying to set iPhone and iPad in 'App Center Listed Platforms'

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

I just published a game for iPhone and iPad that supports Facebook, and now I'm trying to fill in all the App Details on Facebook.

But under "App Center Listed Platforms", I can't switch iOS iPhone and iOS iPad to 'YES'. It says 'this platform cannot be listed because it is either configured incorrectly or not supported in App Center'

I already set the iPhone and iPad Store Id in Settings to the correct one and still no effect.

Any ideas what else that could be? I already searched all forums but couldn't find anything.
Do I have to do something in "Configure App Center Permissions"? I couldn't find any documentation that tells me what those inputs are for.

Comment: Are you using the official Facebook Login SDK for iOS? Otherwise, your app won’t be eligible for listing in App Center.

Comment: I'm using Prime31's plugin for Unity. It looks like they are using the Facebook SDK for iOS.

Comment: Have you turned on Single Sign On for it?

Comment: Single Sign on was the issue. Thanks WizKid!

Comment: If this resolved the issue, please consider writing it up as an answer. If you're the owner of the question, you can accept it to signal to others that this is the solution.

Comment: @PeterBBB please Tick an answer!

Answer (score 8):

Turn on Single Sign-on under App Settings->Basic->iOS->Single Sign-on. (Echoing WizKid above).